# reducer does not update state in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am trying update state using react-redux but the state is not being updated.
new value is coming to 
"if (action.type === 'SET_LOGGED_IN')" 
in reducer, but not updating the isLoggedIn as true. 
What was wrong?
[find the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/148rm8qy9q)

**Login.js**

```
function handleLoginClick(username, password, e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    post('/createUser', { username, password })
        .then(({ status }) => {
            if (status === 200) {
                console.log(this.props);
                this.props.setLoggedIn(true);
                this.props.history.push('/');
            }else{
                this.props.setLoggedIn(false);

            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
        .........
        })
}
..................
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {isLoggedIn : state.reducer.isLoggedIn};};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {setLoggedIn : (value) => dispatch({type: 'SET_LOGGED_IN', value: value}),}};

export default compose(
    withStyles(styles),
    withRouter,
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(NewLogin);
```

**reducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as reduxFormReducer } from 'redux-form';

const initialStates = {
    isLoggedIn : false
};

const reducers = combineReducers({
    reducer : (state = initialStates, action) => {
        //console.log(action);
        if (action.type === 'SET_LOGGED_IN') {
            //console.log(action);
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoggedIn: action.value
            };
        }
        return state;
    },

        form: reduxFormReducer, // mounted under "form"
});

export default reducers;
```

Comment: where you dispatching it ?

Comment: Please share `mapStateToProps` function

Comment: in my Login.js file, please check check 'mapDispatchToProps'

Comment: Please also share `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` is on adding function.

Comment: const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
            isLoggedIn : state.reducer.isLoggedIn,
        };
    };

Comment: @IDF Can you please upload your example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/lOmyoxQw1 It's a react-redux template.

Comment: updated mapStateToProps. @UmairFarooq

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov added https://codesandbox.io/s/148rm8qy9q

Comment: There are errors in codesandbox. Please resolve them. In code sandbox reducers file in empty

Comment: @UmairFarooq updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Fixed the error-

In my code, state is updated correctly. When I accessing, I had used state.isLoggedIn which is undefined. I replaced it from state.reducer.isLoggedIn.
Now everything works charm.

Thank you @UmairFarooq , @VladimirBogomolov and all who commented and gave a try to fix it.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      isLoggedIn : state.reducer.isLoggedIn
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Think there might be a problem with your `mapStateToProps`. Try accessing your isLoggedIn state like :

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {isLoggedIn : state.isLoggedIn};};
```

Answer (score -1):

use componentwillupdate() to controllr when  to update 
return false to not update

Answer (score -1):

You should be calling dispatch differently:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, val) => {
  return {
    setLoggedIn : (val) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_LOGGED_IN', value: val }),
  }
};
```

Try that and it should work for you.

Comment: 'val' defined in (dispatch, val) cannot be used in setLoggedIn.